# Meaning of "an identity of thought and being"

Tags: meaning

> Hegel asserted that in order for the thinking subject (human reason or consciousness) to be able to know its object (the world) at all, there must be in some sense **an identity of thought and being**.

Could you give me an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The word *identity* is being used here in something like its mathematical sense. That is to say that thought and being are inextricable, that they are in essence the same thing, that human thoughts are in some sense governed by the condition of being human animals who interact with the world around us with human senses and human means of locomotion, et cetera.

*Identity*, in this context, means *sameness*. In mathematical (and computing) use, things share an identity if they are precisely the same thing. Adding or subtracting zero, or multiplying or dividing by one are *identity operations*.

In common usage, we are often referring to a metaphorical "on paper" or conceptual representation of ourselves when we use the word *identity*. It isn't exactly who we are, but who we think we are, who others think we are, or the distorted picture of us created by the trails we leave behind.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it is likely that *identity* means something akin to harmony here. So, in mathematical terms, it would be a sort of congruity of thought and being. I'm thinking of what Hegel says in J. Sibree's translation of the *Philosophy of History,* "This comprehension--the penetration of the Ego into and beyond other forms of being with the most profound self-certainty [the identity of subjective and objective Reason being recognized], directly involves the harmonization of Being..." (*Philosophy of History*, 439). Thought, for Hegel, is the *ne plus ultra*of subjectiveness. So, when a man thinks, the object of thought is harmonized and is "no longer an absolutely distinct form of existence" from the intelligible (*POH*, 439). [Edit: *POH* was mistakenly written as *POF*]

That is to say, Hegel does not mean that thought and being are "in essence the same thing," as Mr. Rogers' comment claims. To understand Hegel's use of language and terminology, it is actually important to read Hegel, and Kant.